# Compilation errors when babel and cleveref are included. and other errors when \frontmatter is present

Tags: errors, hyperref, cleveref, front-matter

### Overview

I'm currently re-writing some of my lecture notes in LaTeX. My first language is Spanish, so I'm using the `babel` package. I also wanted to add some utility to the resulting document, like bookmarks and clickable refs. However, just yesterday I stumbled across a compilation error that's halted my progress, and I'm struggling to understand what the problem is.

### Details and MWE

I wrote a test document to check if there were any problems with the packages, and after a lot of testing I ended up with the following code, which I named `main.tex`:

```
\documentclass[10pt, spanish, openany]{memoir}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[pdfencoding=auto, psdextra]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref} % this package breaks everything for some reason
\usepackage[numbered]{bookmark}

\begin{document}
    \frontmatter
    {
        \hypersetup{hidelinks}
        \tableofcontents
    }
    \chapter*{Sample introduction}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Sample introduction} % So this section gets added to ToC
    \blindtext
    \begin{align}
        \label{sample:eq1}
        x + y = 2
    \end{align}
    \blindtext
    \mainmatter
    \chapter{Sample chapter}
    \blindtext
    \section{Sample section}
    \blindtext
\end{document}
```

Some of the packages I included in this test document are not used; however, my original project does make use of them, so I thought it'd be best if I kept them while testing. Now, after messing around, I think I've found the culprit(s): the `babel` (with the `spanish` parameter) and the `cleveref` packages. When these two are included, and the `\frontmatter` command is used, I get a compilation error: `c:/TeX Projects/Hyperref Frontmatter Test/main.tex:24: Missing } inserted. <inserted text>`.

I've also found that removing `\frontmatter` (while keeping both `babel` and `cleveref`) results in a successful compilation. Similarly, when removing either `babel` or `cleveref` (while keeping the `\frontmatter` command), the MWE can be compiled successfully. If possible, I'd like to compile my document while `babel`, `cleveref` and `\frontmatter` are all present. Another thing that's puzzling me is that I'm pretty sure that I was able to compile my original project just fine (with the three now problematic items included) a few weeks ago.

Comment: Which TeX distribution do you employ, and when did you last update it?

Comment: @Mico I use MiKTeX on Windows 10. I re-installed MiKTeX earlier today after encountering this problem (just to see if that would help), got everything up to date again, and still no luck.

Comment: No errors at compilation of your MWE. I use recent version of MiKTeX on Windows 10.

Comment: @Zarko fully up to date? I can replicate iot with a fully up to date TeXLive 2021

Comment: I've removed the `memoir` tag as it is not related to memoir. My answer now actually contains an answer.

Comment: @daleif, ups. Now I test MWE again and get  the same error as you described in your answer (+1). Meanwhile I only update my MiKTeX installation.  If now I remove numbering of equation or spanish babel, MWE works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update: Solution below

---

A bit too long for comment, on a fully up to date TeXLive 2021, I can bould the MWE down to

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\begin{align}
  \label{sample:eq1}
  x + y = 2
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

English works fine. So it seems to be an interaction between `\frontmatter`, `spanish` babel, `amsmath` (as there is no issue with `equation`) and `cleveref`.

What the problem is I don't know. The error I get is

```
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.11 \end{align}
```

---

As Ulrike mentions in the comments, the problem is well known as `spanish` babel messes with Roman numerals.

In the manual for `babel-spanish` it is mentioned that also loading the `babel` option `es-lcroman` leaves the lower case (which `\frontmatter` uses) alone.

Thus this works

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[spanish,es-lcroman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\begin{align}
   \label{sampleEq1}
  x + y = 2
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: roman page numbers, we had that already.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer  Spanish messing with roman numbers? ahh, right there is something about that

Comment: No problem found with (not fully updated)  `pdflatex: security risk: running with elevated privileges
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (MiKTeX 21.3)
entering extended mode
(texstudio_wFQfQi.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4
L3 programming layer <2021-02-18>`

Comment: `*File List*
    book.cls    2020/04/10 v1.4m 
    bk10.clo    2020/04/10 v1.4m
   babel.sty    2021/04/26 3.58 The Babel 
 bblopts.cfg    2005/09/08 v0.1 add Arabic and Farsi to "declared" options of babel
 spanish.ldf
 fontenc.sty
 amsmath.sty    2020/09/23 v2.17i 
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0 
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
  amsopn.sty    2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
cleveref.sty    2018/03/27 v0.21.4 Intelligent cross-referencing
l3backend-pdftex.def    2021-03-18 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)`

Comment: @SimonDispa I have a much newer babel (2021/11/26, v3.67), sadly there is no version on `spanish.ldf`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer added a proper answer.

Comment: Thank you all for your help, the solution provided by @daleif works wonders. There may be a couple small unforeseen consequences in my large scale project, such as having to set `roman` counters in small caps again (since they're now lowercase). It's not a big deal though.

Comment: @txcinder see the mentioned manual, there are other options for Spanish babel

Answer (score 4):

There is a bug in `cleveref`, which does a full expansion with arbitrary code. Legitimate page numbers like the following bomb:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{cleveref}

\renewcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{chapter}\textbf{/}\arabic{page}}

\begin{document}

Text.\label{bug}

\end{document}
```

The problem is the following assignment, in `\label@noarg`:

```
\edef\@tempb{\thepage}%
```

It should read (very likely, because I don't use `cleveref`):

```
\protected@edef\@tempb{\thepage}%
```

Since `\thepage` can be any more or less arbitrary code, we can’t
assume it can be fully expanded with `\edef`. It's a pretty common mistake (and I make it myself from time to time).

There is a similar problem with `greek`, for example.

The bug has been reported to the author, but in the meanwhile, you can use the suggested workarounds. Alternatively, you can modify `cleveref` and see if it works for you.

Comment: `\label@optarg` contains `\edef\@tempb{\thepage}` too hence needs a similar patch.