# How to debug and fix error: Use of \label@optarg doesn't match its definition

Tags: xetex, errors, debugging

I've been having a very bad time lately with the errors produced by this `main.tex` MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{ctable}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\hypertarget{a}{%
\chapter*{A}\label{a}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{a}

\pagenumbering{roman}

\hypertarget{b}{%
\chapter*{B}\label{b}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{b}

\end{document}
```

I'm compiling with both `xelatex main` and overleaf.

1. How should I approach the debugging of these kinds of errors in which I don't have access to the conflicting documents?
2. What are the usual steps you take when debugging a LaTeX issue?
3. What tools do you use to help the process?

Comment: Exactly what is it you are trying to do here wthi that `\hypertarget`? I'd use `\chapter*{A}\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{a}` and I'd drop the label unless you need to refere to the page number of this page somewhere else.

Comment: I'm not using LaTeX directly but markdown and pandoc through this template https://github.com/tompollard/phd_thesis_markdown so I can't really justify some of the decisions. This error happened when I introduced cleveref which is not used in the original template.

Comment: @daleif there is no need for a \phantomsection, hyperref creates a destination also for unnumbered chapter.

Comment: the problem is spanish. It changes the definition of roman numbering in a way that breaks in labels with cleveref. See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/627350/2388

Comment: @UlrikeFischer when did it start doing that? Or is it only for section* we need it.

Comment: Indeed, using `\usepackage[spanish, es-lcroman]{babel}` fixes the issue, thank you! However, I would still like to know how to even begin to debug these issues and find the solution for myself. How can I do that? what tools can I use to get a backtrace for example? where should I look into for the package source files?

Comment: @MateodeMayo there are various tracing commands, e.g. \tracingmacros=1, but it needs a bit experience and an error involving cleveref and writing to files isn't the best to start to learn how to use it. The best here is really to make a minimal example and then to ask.

Comment: @daleif unnumbered sections have destinations too.